# InetAddress cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, ip-address, network-protocols

I'm using the following code to check if the provided ip is reachable in java.

```
public String isNetworkReachable(){
        int timeout = 2000;
        String status = "SUCCESS";
        try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress("10.2.240.74".getBytes());

            if(!address.isReachable(timeout)){
                status = "ERROR";
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return status;

    }
```

WhenI run the code, I get an error saying

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
InetAddress cannot be resolved to a type
InetAddress cannot be resolved
InetAddress cannot be resolved to a type

at com.jkcs.touchpos.sync.SyncUtil.synchronzeManually(SyncUtil.java:83)
at com.jkcs.touchpos.sync.SyncUtil$$FastClassByCGLIB$$6e1c4a07.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
at com.jkcs.touchpos.sync.SyncUtil$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f7d7791c.synchronzeManually(<generated>)
at com.jkcs.touchpos.application.controller.TouchPosWebServiceController.syncStatus(TouchPosWebServiceController.java:864)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:816)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:530)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:426)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:495)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:179)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:930)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:361)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:864)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:243)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:337)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:552)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:979)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:399)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:437)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:435)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

What have I done wrong here. Please help!

Comment: It seems you missed the import. Post your full Class

Comment: By the way, setting `SUCCESS` status by default is incorrect. If an exception occurs during creation of `InetAddress`, the function will return `SUCCESS`.

Comment: Is `com.jkcd.touchpos.sync.SyncUtil` your own class? If so, what is on the failing line 83?

Comment: Also, once you fix your import problem `"10.2.240.74".getBytes()` is **not** going to do what you think it does.

Comment: You could always try compiling your code correctly before trying to execute it.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed because it is an elementary Java mistake. You shouldn't come running to us every time you neglect to add an import to your code. That is likely to lead to you being banned from the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  import `java.net.InetAddress`

2)  Modify function `isNetworkReachable()` slightly:

```
public static String isNetworkReachable(){
    int timeout = 2000;
    String status = "ERROR";
    try {
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("10.2.240.74");

        if(address.isReachable(timeout)){
            status = "SUCCESS";
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return status;

}
```